# Calculate sum of columns from nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
{
    '1000': {
        'owner_id':'1000',
        'in_hours':100,
        'us_hours':200,
        'total_revenue':100
    },
    '1084': {
        'owner_id':'10084',
        'in_hours':100,
        'us_hours':200,
        'total_revenue':100
    }
}
```

Now I need the sum like the following:

```
{
    'in_hours':200,
    'us_hours':400,
    'total_revenue':200
}
```

How to do this? I know I can do this in a loop, but I have a number of keys and I don't want to specify all of them individually.

Comment: In order to do that you will some kind of "rule" that determines which keys are relevant (or not relevant). For example, with the data you've shown it could be keys beginning with 'key' but I suspect it's more complicated than that. Or maybe it's all/any values that are integers?

Comment: Yes. The actual keys are `in_hours, us_hours, in_total, us_total, in_cost, us_cost` like this. All the inner dictionaries has owner

Comment: If you can, please clarify this in the op next time as the information you gave was vague enough to make assumptions on *how* you want to aggregate the data.

Comment: So the numbers can be `float` or `int`? Or just `int`?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this depends on how you determine which values are relevant. Let's assume that you want to sum all values that are integers. In this way we don't need to know what the keys are but just their values.

```
data = {
    '1000': {
        'owner_id':'1000',
        'in_hours':100,
        'us_hours':200,
        'total_revenue':100
    },
    '1084': {
        'owner_id':'10084',
        'in_hours':100,
        'us_hours':200,
        'total_revenue':100
    }
}

result = {}

for v in data.values():
    assert isinstance(v, dict)
    for k, v in v.items():
        if isinstance(v, int):
            result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'in_hours': 200, 'us_hours': 400, 'total_revenue': 200}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know that your keys start with `key` prefix you can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for v in data.values():
    for key, value in v.items():
        if key.startswith('key'):
            result[key] += value

print(dict(result))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    'key1': 200, 
    'key2': 400, 
    'key3': 200
}
```

Comment: actually, as I mentioned in the question, I have a number of keys and I don't want to specify them individually.

Comment: See the updated version, @Happy Coder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collection interface

```
collections.Counter()    
for d in data.values():
        counter.update(d)
result = dict(counter)
    
output 
    {'key3': 200, 'key2': 400, 'key1': 200, 'owner_id': '100841000'}
```

Comment: The output owner_id is probably not what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` and sum up all values of the inner dictionaries which are numbers (`int` or `float`) (so you do not need to know the name). I assume you do not want to concatenate the string IDs (which seem to be redundant, anyway, since they are already the keys to the outer dictionary?):

```
from collections import defaultdict

in_dict = {
    '1000': {
        'owner_id': '1000',
        'key1': 100,
        'key2': 200,
        'key3': 100,
        'time': 0.7
    },
    '1084': {
        'owner_id': '1084',
        'key1': 100,
        'key2': 200,
        'key3': 100,
        'time': 4.5
    }
}

out_dict = defaultdict(int)
for outer in in_dict.values():
    for key, value in outer.items():
        if isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            out_dict[key] += value

print(out_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'key1': 200, 'key2': 400, 'key3': 200, 'time': 5.2})
```

---

A version with `try` and `except` is also possible, so we do not specialize for `int` and `float`:

```
out_dict = defaultdict(int)
for outer in in_dict.values():
    for key, value in outer.items():
        try:
            out_dict[key] += value
        except TypeError:
            # need to remove key due to side effects of defaultdict
            del out_dict[key]

print(out_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'key1': 200, 'key2': 400, 'key3': 200, 'time': 5.2})
```